# Integrating Facebook login php sdk with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am a newbie in Codeigniter and I am trying to integrate the login with facebook app in my codeigniter project. I am running this in localhost.

Issues I am facing are :

1. The login credentials are not getting stored in cookies though I have set cookies to be true.

   `$this->load->library("facebook", array("appId" => "xxx", 
               "secret" => "xxx", "cookie" => true));`
2. Everytime the page loads it checks the facebook credentials and create/update the cookie that I have created with setcookie function. I only want that to happen whenever the user logins/logout.
3. And I want to explicitly set the session and cookie here because I am allowing basic login apart from facebook login as well.
4. When I am passing the email to the process function the cookie value is different from what the actual email is. For example. if my facebook email is `abcd@gmail.com` it's setting the cookie value to be `abcd%40gmail.com`.

Here's my code :

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{

public $user = null;



public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_REQUEST);

    $this->load->library("facebook", array("appId" => "xxx", 
        "secret" => "xxx", "cookie" => true));

    $this->user = $this->facebook->getUser();





}

public function index(){


    if($this->user){

        try{

            $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');

            $email = $user_profile['email'];

            echo $email.'<br />';
            echo $user_profile['first_name'];
            echo $user_profile['last_name'];

            echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->user.'/picture?type=large">';




            $this->process($email);

            }catch(FacebookApiException $e){

            print_r($e);
            $this->user = null;

        }

    }

    if($this->user){

        $logout = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
            "next" => base_url().'login/logout/'));

         echo '<a href="'.$logout.'">Logout</a>';

    }else{ 

        $login = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => 'email'));

        echo '<a href="'.$login.'">Login</a>';

    }

}

public function process($email){

    $cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'utut',
    'value'  => $email,
    'expire' => '86500'
    );

    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

}

public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
    redirect(base_url().'login');
}   

}
```

I got the facebook integration code from somewhere. I don't understand where it is setting the session data here so that I can check it in the beginning.

In short, I want to store the information in the cookies don't want to create/update it all the time I reload the page. Instead of that I would rather check the existence then take actions.